# application_stop.sh: line 4: pm2: command not found

Tags: javascript, angular, pm2, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

In my ec2 instance I am able to run `pm2` command.

[image]

But while deploying application through code deployment I get this error.

[image]

> LifecycleEvent - ApplicationStop
> Script - application_stop.sh
> [stdout]Stopping any existing node servers
> [stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/878477e5-6ffb-4175-8e9e-97045ea99290/d-HVRQ58IBL/deployment-archive/application_stop.sh: line 4: pm2: command not found

My application_stop.sh code.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Stopping existing node servers
echo "Stopping any existing node servers"
pm2 stop main
```

As per @ranjanistic I checked my pm2 path using `which pm2` command and it returned

`~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/pm2`

After that I update my application_stop.sh using this below command

`~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/pm2 start main`

Also added symbolic link like this to npm, node and pm2.

///this process worked. Thanks @ranjanistic

```
which npm
which node
which pm2

sudo ln -s /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/npm
sudo ln -s /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/node
sudo ln -s /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/pm2
```

Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary executable reference to your command needs to be available in the environment you're expecting to run it from.

You are using npm to run a pm2 command, which means it is installed as a local module. Therefore you can similarly create another npm script like `npm run stop:all` with your pm2 command, it should work.

If you're running it in a bash script, the command reference binary should be available in `PATH`. Or you can also use your command by mentioning its binary path instead of name, independent of wherever the binary is located, for example

If pm2 is installed as a global node module

```bash
/usr/bin/pm2 stop main # or whatever the path to the binary is.
```

Or if pm2 is installed as a node module in project then

```bash
./node_modules/bin/pm2 stop main # again, path to pm2 binary can be anything, you'll have to know beforehand
```

Also, I'd recommend a separate config file for each of your pm2 applications, so that you can use it anywhere without worrying whether your `main` app is available to pm2 or not.

You may also need to check if `npm` or `node` commands are running or not, and based on that you may add the path to your folder containing pm2 in `$PATH` variable before running the deployment. You can check the path to pm2 manually using `which pm2` if it is available.

Comment: `which pm2` gives me this path `~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/pm2` How do I make it work directly pm2 instead of full absolute url ?

Comment: `export PATH="$PATH:~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin"` Use this before running pm2 command

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide absolute path like this **/usr/bin/pm2**

Comment: Is it still necessary if I have installed pm2 globally ?

Comment: "globally" is a relative term.